# What does "$[N/2]$" mean when used as an upper bound in summation notation?

Tags: summation, notation

I encountered a sum symbol like ($N$ is a positive integer):

$$\sum_{i=0}^{[N/2]}f_i$$

where the upper bound is put in square brackets $[N/2]$. I know that i.e. $\lfloor x\rfloor$ would mean the floor function. What does it mean when the upper bound is in square brackets?

Comment: Square brackets is another common notation for the floor function.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for letting me know!